# React Native Nested ScrollView Can`t Scroll on Android Device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the problem about nested scrollview on Android Device, but IOS OK

How to fix the issue about B scrollview cant scrolling ?

```
<ScrollView>  // A ScrollView
    <View><Text>Hello</Text></View> 
    <View><Text>Hello</Text></View> 
    <View><Text>Hello</Text></View> 
    <View><Text>Hello</Text></View> 
    <View>       
        <ScrollView> // B ScrollView
            <View><Text>Hello</Text></View>         
            <View><Text>Hello</Text></View>         
            <View><Text>Hello</Text></View>          
            <View><Text>Hello</Text></View>      
        </ScrollView> 
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 78):

If API 21 as minimum target is an option, you could upgrade to react-native 0.56.x and try the [new prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#nestedscrollenabled) `nestedScrollEnabled`.

Note: it is meant to be used in the child scrollview, i.e.

```
<ScrollView {...parentProps}>
  <ScrollView {...childProps} nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
  </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Dear Alberto, I have a horizontal ScrollView which contains another horizontal scrollView, I've tried your solution but it doesn't work on android. Any idea?

Comment: Nested horizontal ScrollViews are confirmed to not work on Android - see https://snack.expo.io/@harrytravelchime/827f87 for an example. In fact, this is a big problem even with the native components: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44798354/android-nestedscrollview-how-to-make-it-horizontal/44798533

Comment: Dude, after 3 days of trying to get a scrollable drag-and-drop to work inside a ScrollView container, u just saved my life.

Comment: I wish I could upvote multiple times...

thank you it works

Comment: It fixed, but I didn't understand how it worked as in doc it says by default it is true https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#nestedscrollenabled-android

Comment: `nestedScrollEnabled` is veryyyy janky in my experience. It just doesn't work well. React Native does a poor job deciding which view should be scrolled when the user pans their finger, sometimes it will scroll the outer view when it feels like it shouldn't, sometimes it will scroll in the inner view.

The best thing to do is import the scroll view from "react-native-gesture-handler", works wayyy better on android in my experience.

Comment: Doesnt work for me

Answer (score 18):

Add "nestedScrollEnabled={true}" property to the internal ScrollView and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

React-native ScrollView component uses Android [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) when you run app in android.

Android ScrollView doesn't support nested scrolling by default. You need to use [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) to achieve nested scrolling in android.

Comment: thanks, but how to use NestedScrollView in my react native case ?

Comment: Sorry, i still not understand about coustom native ui for android doc, would you like to explain more about my case ?

Comment: Is it can solve my case with using custom native ui NestedScrollView ?
I dont know where to create custom viewManager class file.

Comment: Try https://github.com/Neson/react-native-android-design-support/blob/master/lib/NestedScrollViewAndroid.js

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Could you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437251/unable-to-scroll-in-scrollview

Answer (score 2):

https://gist.github.com/ashrithks/8d97f928d92643468a26e29c4d2dbb67

try the above ,
expo link:-
https://snack.expo.io/S11vIpHA-

hacky way

Comment: Your way works, but there is a problem when setting the wrapper view that wraps the nested scrollview to flex view and changing the height of the nested scrollview to 700 or any height that would show in fullscreen only the nested view and scroll all the end of the scrollview you will not scroll up again. You can see edited code: https://snack.expo.io/SJYzbXGmV

Comment: @0x01Brain , use https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.57/scrollview#nestedscrollenabled supported by react-native now

Comment: @AshrithKS `<ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled>` worked 2022 thanks

Answer (score 0):

In ScrollView, set style of contentContainerStyle to `flex: 1`:

```
<ScrollView>  // A ScrollView
    <View><Text>Hello</Text></View> 
    <View><Text>Hello</Text></View> 
    <View><Text>Hello</Text></View> 
    <View><Text>Hello</Text></View> 
    <View>       
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}> // B ScrollView
            <View><Text>Hello</Text></View>         
            <View><Text>Hello</Text></View>         
            <View><Text>Hello</Text></View>          
            <View><Text>Hello</Text></View>      
        </ScrollView> 
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

It worked for me on android. Let me know if it works for you please.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Could you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437251/unable-to-scroll-in-scrollview

Comment: Same here, It's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, I had verticle scroll and inside verticle scroll.
I made a state and give the scrollEnabled to the outer scrollview and inside added the onTouchStart,onTouchEnd and onTouchCancel functions and change the state of the outer scroll to false so I can easily scroll.
**you can also try the same approach with ref**

```
const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(true);

<ScrollView scrollEnabled={scroll}>
  ... other components
 <ScrollView 
  onTouchStart={ => setScroll(false)}
  onTouchEnd={ => setScroll(true)}
  onTouchCancel={ => setScroll(true)}
 >
 ... inside other components
 </ScrollView>
 ... other components 
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work properly when the user touch is fast