# React-native Listview inside Scrollview not scrolling in android

Tags: android, react-native

In our React-native project, We have a screen which is having a parent Scrollview(with pull to refresh) and with in scrollview we have Listview (as chilld view).

In iOS we are able to scroll Scrollview(Parent) as well as Listview(child view).

But in android, We are not able to scroll the Child Listview. When we try to scroll the child Listview, The Parent view is getting scrolled. The child view is not getting the Touch.

Is this related to React-native issue? Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

Code snippet:

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainerStyle} refreshControl={this.getRefreshControl()}>
      <View> Some header </View>
      <MyComponent> </MyComponent>
      <ListView /* This list view is not scrolling in Android */
        dataSource={dataSource}
        initialListSize={10}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
        renderSeparator={this.renderSeparator}/>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: please can u show me the ur current code

Comment: what u r triede...?

Comment: update ur code first...

Comment: @Prashantpattar, I have added code snippet. Pls check.

Comment: i think ur listview is small . Try setting flex: 1 or height: 587 on your ListView's style property.

Comment: Check out this response: [Make Nested ScrollViews Scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53501692/10371717)

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've done a ListView which is scrollable if you want !

**ListBillScreen.js**

```
export default class ListBillScreen extends React.Component{

  /*Constructor*/

  render() {
  return (

  <ScrollView style = {styles.container}>

    <View style ={styles.header}>
      <Text style = {styles.textHeader}> Title</Text>
    </View>

  <ListView
    style={styles.listView}
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={(data) => <Row {...data} navigator={this.props.navigator} />}
    renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style=
    {styles.separator} />}
  />
  <AndroidBackButton
    onPress={this.popIfExists.bind(this)}
  />
</ScrollView>
);
```

}
}

**Styles**

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Colors, Metrics } from '../../Themes'

export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
  paddingTop: 20,
  backgroundColor: Colors.background
},
separator: {
  height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
  backgroundColor: '#8E8E8E',
},
textHeader: {
  color: Colors.steel,
  textAlign: 'center',
},
image: {
  height:64,
  width: 64,
},
listView: {
  paddingTop: 10,
  paddingBottom: 20
},
actionButtonIcon: {
  fontSize: 20,
  height: 22,
  color: 'white',
},
})
```

It's fully scrollable even if you add some rows =) (My rows are created with a JSon File, with the **Row.js**)

Enjoy !

Comment: I have also same code almost. But it is working only on iOS. Did you check the code in Android?

Comment: If i remove refreshControl property from the scrollview. It is working form me also. But it is not working with RefreshControl which is used for pull to refresh functionality. The one  missing in ur code RefreshControl.

Answer (score -1):

i think ur listview is small . Try setting flex: 1 or height: 587 on your ListView's style property. –

Answer (score -1):

Both listview and scrollview touch events are conflicting.

Try using below code in your fragment/activity

```
listview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is what happening exactly. But where we need to add this code in react-native android project ?

Comment: Dear Tutu, did you find out where to put this code in react native?

Answer (score -1):

You need to set nestedScrollEnabled = true for ListView.