# Android nestedScrollView - how to make it horizontal?

Tags: android

I cant seem to find an option for [nestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) to make it horizontal instead of vertical.  i have been using HorizontalScrollView but i'd like to switch to nested. Is there anyway to do this ? searching the docs i dont see it yet it does say its the same as a scrollview ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**No**

I do not believe `NestedScrollView` can be scrolled horizontally. According to docs:

> **For vertical scrolling**, consider NestedScrollView instead of scroll view which offers greater user interface flexibility and support for the material design scrolling patterns.

As per the text in bold, I believe `NestedScrollViews` were only made to scroll vertically.

While `NestedScrollViews` are "just like `ScrollView`" ([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)), the docs do also state that:

> Scroll view supports vertical scrolling only. For horizontal scrolling, use HorizontalScrollView instead.

(Both blockquotes come from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html))

Comment: HorizontalScrollView is always poor.....!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

simply just use "HorizontalScrollView" instead

Answer (score 0):

There is no support to enable the Horizantal nested scrollview in android.
Support is only limited to vertical scrollview.

Comment: So it's not possible?

Comment: Can find the ways to replicate it in different way but not using simply Horizontal Scroll view

Answer (score -2):

`NestedScrollViews` is not a good approach . Better approach is to use `recyclerview` iniside another `recyclerview`.

Comment: Can you explain that further?

Comment: I guess he means that RecyclerView is better for large number of child views because they do not create all child views eagerly but lazily unlike all scroll views. For smaller  layouts it's not worth the complexity of RVs.

Comment: Not necessarily. It really depends on the use case. If you have a relatively small no. of items to display, NestedScrollView is perfectly fine. For large datasets, recyclerview is a better approach.