# Vertical ViewPager with HorizontalScrollView inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, horizontalscrollview, touch-event

I have a [`VerticalViewPager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/src/com/android/deskclock/VerticalViewPager.java) whose `Fragment` content I want to scroll horizontally. The vertical paging works fine until the horizontal content is big enough to scroll. After that the touch events are not passed on to the `ViewPager` and so paging no longer works.

#### MVCE

This can be reproduced by setting up a simple project as given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46826363/3681880) that I just posted.

Replace the `fragment_one.xml` file with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and set the text to anything long enough to scroll horizontally.

#### Things I've tried

- [`NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html): That quickly turned out to be a dead end since it is apparently [not available for horizontal scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44798533/3681880). I thought about converting the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/1fcce44/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.java) to a `HorizontalNextedScrollView` but that would not be a trivial project.
- Custom `HorizontalScrollView`: I tried converting answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8330827/3681880) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7703740/3681880) for horizontal scrolling, but was unsuccessful. I'm going to continue experimenting in this area.
- This is not a [DoubleViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30594064/3681880) but I feel like the solution should be similar.

Comment: I happened to write something similar, but my case is a VerticalViewPager and HorizontalViewPager instead of HorizontalScrollView, I wrote a blog about it, perhaps this will help someone looking into this topic: https://bloggie.io/@_junrong/implementing-bidirectional-viewpager-by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to answer this and other similar questions, it is very helpful to understand how the Android Framework handles touch events. My [fuller answer on that is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46862320/3681880), but I will include the summary diagram below.

[image]

The `HorizontalScrollView` (ViewGroup B in the diagram) is handling all touch events before the `VerticalViewPager` (ViewGroup A) has a chance to. So the solution is to use `onInterceptTouchEvent()` in the `VerticalViewPager` to selectively filter out vertical scrolls. For that it is easiest to just use a `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.onScroll()`.

Here are the relevant changes you need to make to the [`VerticalViewPager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/src/com/android/deskclock/VerticalViewPager.java) class to accomplish that:

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {

    GestureDetector mDetector;

    private void init() {
        // ...
        mDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new VerticalScrollListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onInterceptTouchEvent(flipXY(ev));
        flipXY(ev);

        return mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    class VerticalScrollListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, 
                                float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            return Math.abs(distanceY) > Math.abs(distanceX);
        }
    }
}
```